# What will be a quick way to parse bits used per frame for an encoded H264 bitstream in JM?

Tags: h.264

What will be a quick way to parse bits used per frame for an encoded H264 bitstream in JM?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average number of bits, just take `number_of_bits/number_of_frames`.  For bits from an individual frame, you're going to have to decode the actual bitsream.

Comment: Can you print bits per picture in JM Reference software ?